# Prometheus Alertmanager dc alert message onyl dc team

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

My devices in different locations follow them through Prometheus and alertmanager, when the Prometheus alertmanager triggers, it goes to all teams.
Notifying the relevant datacenter team when there is a warning generated by Prometheus. In the example below, what I want to do is to report the problem that occurs in the Boston data center to the Boston team, how can I do this?
Thanks.

Prometheus `config.yml`:

```
    labels:
      dc: BOSTON
      name: BOS_APP_Server
      type: physical
  - targets:
    - 10.10.10.9:9100
    labels:
      dc: NEWY
      name: NEWY_APP_Server
      type: physical
  - targets:
    - 10.10.11.90:9100
    labels:
      dc: UTH
      name: UTH_FileServer
      type: physical
  - targets:
    - 10.10.12.99:9100`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the Alertmanager with something like this:

```
route:
  # Default receiver
  receiver: 'report-team'
 
  routes:
    - receiver: 'boston-team'
      match_re:
        dc: BOSTON
 
    - receiver: 'newy-team'
      match_re:
        dc: NEWY
 
    - receiver: 'uth-team'
      match_re:
        dc: UTH
 
receivers:
  - name: 'report-team'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'REPORT-TEAM-EMAIL@SERVER'
 
  - name: 'boston-team'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'BOSTON-TEAM-EMAIL@SERVER'

  - name: 'newy-team'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'NEWY-TEAM-EMAIL@SERVER'

  - name: 'uth-team'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'UTH-TEAM-EMAIL@SERVER'
```

See more info at the Alertmanager configuration [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/).